# What will happen if i remove @Autowired from field/constructor injection but injecting that bean in another class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired, spring-annotations

Suppose i have a class as,

```
@Repository
public class StudentServiceDao{

private final StudentClient client;
private final StudentValidator validator;

@Autowired  <----
public StudentServiceDao(StudentClient studentClient){
   client = studentClient;
   validator = new StudentValidator(studentClient.getIdentifier()); 
  }

public List<Student> getStudent(Request request){
  StudentRS studentRS= client.getStudentList(request);
  validator.validate(studentRS);
  return StudentMapper.map(studentRS);
}
}
```

Now i have another class as,

```
@Component
public class StudentServiceDaoImpl{

@Autowired
private StudentServiceDao studentServiceDao;

public list<Student> retrieveStudent (Request request){
  return studentServiceDao.getStudent(request);
}
}
```

Now if i remove **@Autowired** from StudentServiceDao what will happen and why ?

Comment: Well, what happens when you do it? What does the javadoc of Autowired say? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

Comment: It's working in both the way. But, i have encounter a "Out of memory" error intermittently when using implicit constructor autowiring.

Comment: The OOM has absolutely nothing to do with how you are autowiring.

Comment: If somehow context initialization gets failed due to bean creation, what will happen ?

Comment: Unless you did something weird, the app won't start, and you'll get an exception stack trace in the console. Why don't you simply test it?

Answer (score 0):

Autowiring can happen multiple ways.

For a few years now (currently 2020) all of these are valid ways to autowire dependencies:

Explicit constructor autowire annotation:

```
@Repository
public class StudentServiceDao {

    private final StudentClient client;
    private final StudentValidator validator;

    @Autowired
    public StudentServiceDao(StudentClient studentClient){
        client = studentClient;
        validator = new StudentValidator(studentClient.getIdentifier()); 
    }
}
```

Implicit constructor autowire:

```
@Repository
public class StudentServiceDao {

    private final StudentClient client;
    private final StudentValidator validator;

    public StudentServiceDao(StudentClient studentClient){
        client = studentClient;
        validator = new StudentValidator(studentClient.getIdentifier()); 
    }
}
```

Explicit field autowire:

```
@Repository
public class StudentServiceDao {

    @Autowired
    private final StudentClient client;
    @Autowired
    private final StudentValidator validator;
}
```

Pick which ever one makes the most sense for you. I personally like implicit constructor. I think it makes instantiating the bean for testing easier with mocks. All types are valid.

5 or 6 years ago, before java config took over, there were other requirements like getters/setters needing to be present, xml files needing to specify all the beans, etc. But those are mostly gone and if you are working on a modern spring app you won't encounter them.

As to why, I have no idea, this is just how it is.